# showing data in tool tip of a PieChart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm accessing a GITHUB raw file and using the `d3.pie()` function making the start and end angles of the pie, at that point the data is showing on console but when I access it in tooltip it gives `UNDEFINED`.

Do run the code if you can, the link to my github is given where I'm loading my file `d3.csv()` also FUNCTION TEST is running only once I need to run it till my data runs out.

```
//CALCULATING RADIUS OF CHART
var radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2 - margin
//APPENDING SVG IN DIV HAVING ID pieChart
var svg = d3.select("#pieChart")
.append("svg")
.attr("width", width)
.attr("height", height)
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");
// DATA
d3.csv 
("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Dehya/django/master/pkpopulation.csv? 
token=AHXLL23PHQSJGYIYCLA6YX25I7IJA",function(error, data){ 
// GETTING VALUES AS POPULATION FROM DATA AND CALCULATING THE START AND 
END 
ANGLE:
var pie = d3.pie()
.value(function(d) {return d.population; })
 console.log(pie(data));
//SETTING COLOR SCALE
var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .domain(data)
    .range(["red", "yellow", "green", "blue", "orange"])

function Test(d){ 
    for( i ; i<data.length ; i++)
    {
         console.log(data[i].name + " : " + data[i].population);
         return data[i].name + " : " + data[i].population;
    }
    }

//MAKING TOOPTIP
var tip = d3.tip()
    .attr("class", "d3-tip")
    .offset([-10, 0])
    .html(Test(data));
  svg.call(tip);
//MAKING SLICES OF PIE CHART
svg
    .selectAll("mySlices")
    .data(pie(data))
    .enter()
    .append("path")
        .attr('d',d3.arc()
            .innerRadius(0)
            .outerRadius(radius)
         )
        .attr("fill", function(d){ return color(d.data.key) })
        .attr("stroke","black")
        .style("stroke-width","1px")
        .style("opacity",0.7)
    .on("mouseover", tip.show)
    .on("mouseout", tip.hide);  
});
```

Comment: Hey! It looks like the URI that you're pointing to in the code, for the CSV, is not available. Is the file private / unavailable?

Comment: yes the file is private, nvm got it done thank u :)